# Why is compiling a code affecting lambda to std::function so slow, in particular with Clang?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang, std-function

I discovered that compile time of a relatively small amount of code, converting lambda functions to `std::function<>` values, can be very high, in particular with Clang compiler.

Consider the following dummy code that creates 100 lambda functions:

```
#if MODE==1
#include <functional>
using LambdaType = std::function<int()>;
#elif MODE==2
using LambdaType = int(*)();
#elif MODE==3
#include "function.h" // https://github.com/skarupke/std_function
using LambdaType = func::function<int()>;
#endif

static int total=0;

void add(LambdaType lambda)
{
    total += lambda();
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    add([]{ return 1; });
    add([]{ return 2; });
    add([]{ return 3; });
    // 96 more such lines...
    add([]{ return 100; });

    return total == 5050 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Depending on `MODE` preprocessor macro, that code can select between the following three ways to pass by a lambda function to `add` function:

1. `std::function<>` template class
2. a simple C pointer to function (possible here only because there is no capture)
3. a fast replacement to `std::function` written by Malte Skarupke (https://probablydance.com/2013/01/13/a-faster-implementation-of-stdfunction/)

Whatever the mode, the program always exit with a regular `0` error code.
But now look at compilation time with Clang:

```
$ time clang++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=1 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m8.162s
user    0m7.828s
sys 0m0.318s

$ time clang++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=2 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.056s
sys 0m0.046s

$ time clang++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=3 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m0.870s
user    0m0.814s
sys 0m0.051s

$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Whow. There is a 80 times compile time difference between `std::function` and pointer to function modes ! And even a 10 times difference between `std::function` and its replacement.

How can it be? Is there a performance problem specific to Clang or is it due to the inherent complexity of `std::function` requirement?

I tried to compile the same code with GCC 5.4 and Visual Studio 2015. There are also big compile time differences, but not as much.

**GCC**:

```
$ time g++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=1 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m1.179s
user    0m1.080s
sys 0m0.092s

$ time g++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=2 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m0.136s
user    0m0.120s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time g++ -c -std=c++11 -DMODE=3 lambdas.cpp 
real    0m1.994s
user    0m1.792s
sys 0m0.196s
```

**Visual Studio**:

```
C:\>ptime cl /c /DMODE=1 /EHsc /nologo lambdas.cpp
Execution time: 2.411 s

C:\>ptime cl /c /DMODE=2 /EHsc /nologo lambdas.cpp
Execution time: 0.270 s

C:\>ptime cl /c /DMODE=3 /EHsc /nologo lambdas.cpp
Execution time: 1.122 s
```

I am now considering using Malte Skarupke's implementation, both for a slight better runtime performance and for a big compile time enhancement.

Comment: Did you take a look at the generated assembly? Maybe there is some fancy optimization going on.

Comment: Fun fact: With `-O3` gcc optimizes the function pointer version to 37 lines of assembly (on my machine). I think it can compute the result 5050 at compile time. For comparison: For `std::function` gcc generates about 8000 lines of assembly. There seems to be a lot of complexity involved when using `std::function`, which would explain the compile time.

Comment: @pschill Interesting observation, GCC can indeed make great optimization in some cases! I deliberately measure compile time without optimization. And no, I didn't think to look at generated code for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what the compiler has to process in each case with the --save-temps option.
On my machine with clang 6.0.1, MODE=1 generates a 575K preprocessed file, due to the multitude of standard library headers being included.
The MODE=1 generates a 416 *byte* file, 1000 times smaller.
The generated assembly is also different by a factor of 10.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to test and interpret the example you have, however, from Clang 9.0.0 on, it has the ability to make a time trace of your compilation. See [phoronix article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-Clang-9.0-Time-Trace#:%7E:text=LLVM%20has%20merged%20a%20very,and%20other%20areas%20for%20improvement.) for an impression and links to more info. In short, you can get a json of what it's doing that you can visualize in a nice graphic by adding `-ftime-trace` to the command line.

If you notice something really strange, you can always log a bug at bugs.llvm.org with a good reproduction (I think changing some wording of this question would be fine)

Let me also add a small comment about the testing code. I'm not surprised that the `std:: function` is slower to compile, as this requires an extra include to parse. (And standard library includes are huge) Also for the run-time, the slow effect is logical as `std:: function` is adding a lot of extra indirection which can't be optimized away.

I would recommend adding a 4th year case where add is a template and the function type the template argument:

```
template<typename LambdaType>
void add(LambdaType &&lambda)
{
    total += lambda();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered something similar, but related to RAM usage:

I have an [RTTI library](https://github.com/Langulus/RTTI/blob/main/source/MetaData.inl), that wraps a lot of type related functions (like constructors and destructors) in lambdas, and stores them in std::functions.
Since the reflector instantiates for each type in use, it had an enormous RAM footprint (required about 80 GB of memory to **just compile**).

After a lot of pondering and searching for self-inflicted pathologic metaprogramming, I narrowed the problem down to std::function, and was able to lower RAM usage from 80 GB to **4 GB**, just by using raw function pointers and the + lambda trick.

The RAM overhead seemed to be consistent across all compilers I currently use:

- Clang 15.0.1 (MSVC's clang-cl variant)
- MSVC 19.35.32215.0

My guess is that there's some fundamental metaprogramming booboo involved with all std::function implementations.